# How do I record user input on IOS application in Swift?

Tags: swift, database, user-input

I'm creating an application that asks the user questions in order to make them a custom exercise program. I have the user interface set-up for the user to be able to answer the questions. How do I log the input of the user? I need to be able to record their answers and log them in order to feed the user with the result based on their answers.

Sorry for the basic question, this is my first project.

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea where to even start. Google showed me results that didn't even come close to my solving my problem. Probably due to my lack of knowledge of the proper terms used by developers.

I'd like for the input to be recorded in order to create the program for the user. Currently, the buttons I use to record the answers do nothing at all.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep track of the values in your running app or are you asking how to persist the data so it can be loaded each time the app is started?

Comment: Keep track of the values while it's running. Thanks.

Comment: This question is very board. Please try to be more specific on the user input type you are attempting to collect, ex: text, touch, controls.

Comment: I'm trying to collect information from button presses and numbers chosen on a horizontal slider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITextField dragged onto the storyboard. Then you should pull up the class that governs the UIViewController you're working with using the [assistant editor that looks like two circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqJJe.png) and you can create a connection to the UITextField here by right click and dragging to the code shown. It will create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZL1Y.png):

```
 @IBOutlet var total: UITextField!
```

and then you can get the text by doing total.text or textfield.text or using whatever you decide to call your textfield variable when you drag it into the assistant editor.
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) link should help if you have further questions about UITextFields